# EyeFi doesn't support CF cards. Are there any alternatives that do?

Tags: wireless, compactflash, eye-fi

Pretty much as what the title asks. Any ideas anyone?
 Is there any particular, technical limitation for using this technology with CF cards?

Comment: On Eye-Fi supporting CF cards, I think it would be best to ask them. On the alternatives, I don't suppose you tried using an Eye-Fi in a SD-to-CF adapter? No other options come to mind.

Comment: @Itai - I dod not try an adapter, and from what I have read they are limited in their usability. I hope maybe one of the forum member has actual experience with using such device in his CF only camera, so we can all learn from a 1st hand experience.

Comment: My understanding is that the adapters work best when shooting JPEG, that trying to shoot raw usually results in failure.

Comment: Edited to make the question answerable without having to speculate about EyeFi's business model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the latest answer on CF adapters for the 5DmkII and the 7D, on our site.

[Instant Photo Transfer from CF Cameras](http://www.eyefi.com/lp/cf)

Thx,

Ziv.
Eye-Fi co-founder

Comment: @mattdm - I've updated to the latest information. Looks like it's now coming to a CF card near you... :)

Answer (score 2):

Thus far, Eye-Fi does not support compact flash.  They have a page on their website that lists [known issues when using an adapter](http://support.eye.fi/product-info/camera-compatibility/compatibility/known-issues-with-compact-flash-card-adapters/).  These issues include a **reduced wireless range of the Eye-Fi card** as well as a **potential for file corruption**.

I'm not aware of any competitor's products which offer similar functionality in a CF card.  I do note however that it seems DSLR manufacturers are starting to move to SD from CF, with newer models from both Canon and Nikon favoring the SD cards.

Comment: @ahockley - yes, I have found that page on their website. I was wondering if there is a particular reason **why** they do not support CF.

Comment: If you want the true reason from the company, you'll probably get a more accurate answer by asking the company than by asking here.

Comment: How would anyone here on photo.se.com know the answer to 'why'?

Comment: @Jay Lance Photography - the intent is to ask about the technical reason, not their business model/decision. Anyway, I accept your edit.

Comment: Fair enough. You might want to edit the question to that goal, then... Maybe this: "From a technical standpoint are there any reasons that EyeFi can't support CF cards? Are there any alternatives that do?" That will clarify the question and avoid speculative answers...

Comment: @yasp more likely is the commercial viability -- SD is defacto for consumer cameras and entry levle DSLRs which gives a wide possible audience. CF is generally used by higher level cameras and most of those support tethered shooting which would eat in at the people *wanting* the product.

Comment: @Rowland Shaw - You can argue that this is actually in favor of designing a CD Eye-Fi. Targeted at the pro/semipro market, it can be a premium product with spiced up price and margins. Hopefully @Ziv will give us a hint on that.

Comment: @yasp Of course, that would also compete with the Wireless File Transmitters already made by Canon (albeit a tad on the expensive side) - I'd assume Nikon/etc. have equivalents.

Comment: @Rowland Shaw - that's right.

Comment: I'm thinking that the metal frames/bodies of the hardcore pro cameras might pose a bit of a problem for a transmitter embedded somewhere it wasn't designed to be. And the physical size of the device precludes an antenna that I would (as a pro, which I once was even if I no longer am) trust for anything more than a go/no-go signal over any real distance. And how about interference from a microdrive spinning in the slot next door (some photogs still prefer them to solid state)? I'd have to see a lot of third-party evidence of reliability before I'd trust it, esp. for two-way.

Comment: @Stan, sure but metal body and CF card don't imply each other. For example, the D7000 has a magnesium body but uses SDHC cards.

Comment: A metal body doesn't imply CF, but most CF-using 35mm-format cameras (of current vintage) are metal-bodied. How well does EyeFi work in the D7000? (That's a question, not a jab -- I haven't investigated, I'm just an ex-radio tech.)

Comment: @Stan Rogers - I am surprised that you mentioned some photogs still prefer MicroDrives. Now that SS reached 128GB, I wonder what is a good reason for this preference.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some evolution on that point. Eye-Fi seems to be willing to offer CF support, by certifying CF adapters for their SD Eye-fi, starting March 2015. More infos on their website:

http://www.eyefi.com/lp/cf

You will find a how-to guide and a list of compatible cameras. And also some words on possible drawbacks, like slower transfer times.

Comment: That's good news... From their website looks like the technical problem we were questioning about was the regular metal casing of the CF cards (that would not explain, though, what prevents them from actually making a custom CF card with WiFi). Nevertheless, the certified adapter should work just great.

Comment: <sarcasm> Now that it took them 4 years to finally answer to our request, let's hope that the market price for the EyeFi cards will get reasonable before we have to replace our aging non-wireless cameras... At an age where an 16GB SD can be bought at some $8, they sell their EyeFi for $60 (dang, I can see a whole wireless adapter grip kit for $105 for my 7D). </sarcasm>

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt there's a technical reason. I'm sure that they just don't see offering a CF version as profitable.

Comment: see my comment to Rowland Shaw at ahockley's answer.